# jquery simple image slideshow tutorial

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow

Where can I find a simple jquery image slideshow tutorial for beginners from scratch (without plugins) without left and right navigation button?

thank you.

Answer (score 51):

This is by far the easiest example I have found on the net.
http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Summaring the example, this is what you need to do a slideshow:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="active" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
</div>
```

Position absolute is used to put an each image over the other.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .active{
        z-index:99;
    }
</style>
```

The image that has the class="active" will appear over the others, the class=active property will change with the following **Jquery** code.

```
<script>
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('div#slideshow IMG.active');
        var $next = $active.next();    

        $next.addClass('active');

        $active.removeClass('active');
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    });
</script>
```

If you want to go further with slideshows I suggest you to have a look at the link above (to see animated oppacity changes - 2n example) or at other more complex slideshows tutorials.

Comment: I think there is a certain progression by coders where we start off figuring out how to write a simple fade show, using the upper/lower layer technique, but eventually we realize that what we want is to actually move the pictures from left to right (or vice versa).

Comment: this is the simplest and straight-forward example! thanks for your help man

Answer (score 19):

I dont know why you havent marked on of these gr8 answers... here is another option which would enable you and anyone else visiting to control transition speed and pause time

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function () {

    /* SET PARAMETERS */
    var change_img_time     = 5000; 
    var transition_speed    = 100;

    var simple_slideshow    = $("#exampleSlider"),
        listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen             = listItems.length,
        i                   = 0,

        changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
            });

        };

    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);

});
```

.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="exampleSlider">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

.
If your keeping this simple its easy to keep it resposive
best to visit the: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sagive/cAsB3/)

.
If you want something with special transition FX (Still responsive) - check this out
[DEMO WITH SPECIAL FX](http://jsfiddle.net/7w9351tb/142/)

Comment: Love this simple and elegant code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks man, glad u like it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my adaptation of Michael Soriano's tutorial. See below or in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xecowoq/edit?html,css,js,output).

```js
$(function() {
  var theImage = $('ul#ss li img');
  var theWidth = theImage.width();
  //wrap into mother div
  $('ul#ss').wrap('<div id="mother" />');
  //assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
  $('#mother').css({
    width: function() {
      return theWidth;
    },
    height: function() {
      return theImage.height();
    },
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  });
  //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 
  var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
  $('ul').css({
    width: function() {
      return totalWidth;
    }
  });

  var ss_timer = setInterval(function() {
    ss_next();
  }, 3000);

  function ss_next() {
    var a = $(".active");
    a.removeClass('active');

    if (a.hasClass('last')) {
      //last element -- loop
      a.parent('ul').animate({
        "margin-left": (0)
      }, 1000);
      a.siblings(":first").addClass('active');
    } else {
      a.parent('ul').animate({
        "margin-left": (-(a.index() + 1) * theWidth)
      }, 1000);
      a.next().addClass('active');
    }
  }

  // Cancel slideshow and move next manually on click
  $('ul#ss li img').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(ss_timer);
    ss_next();
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#ss {
  list-style: none;
}
#ss li {
  float: left;
}
#ss img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ss">
  <li class="active">
    <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado-colors.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/monte-vista.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please post your jsfiddle? I tried and the image was going off the page.

Comment: Added. You probably just need to update your LI elements to `float:left;`

Answer (score 3):

This lookslike something you would be interested in

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-gallery/