# how to make pics slide in my slidediv in asp.net from database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, slideshow, slide

I have a slidediv. I am retrieving images from database where the file-path are saved. 
Now I am using the below code to set image in the div. But I want to show my all images that are present in the database one by one after some seconds in the div. How to do that??

### Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From pictable", objsqlconn);
    SqlDataReader grpIDreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    grpIDreader.Read();
    string path = grpIDreader["pic1"].ToString();
    slidediv.Attributes["style"] = String.Format("background-image:url('{0}')", path);
}
```

i want to get this done on pageload() from database and the images will show in the slidediv for some seconds each..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using simple ajax control inside Ajax-tool kit provided by Microsoft.

The link is http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/SlideShow/SlideShow.aspx

Or you need to use jQuery or Java-Script for the same.

Some Links

1. [jquery simple image slideshow tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068734/jquery-simple-image-slideshow-tutorial)